# F# script can't load .Net 4.5?

Tags: f#, .net-4.5

I have an F# library that uses the .Net 4.5 HttpClient. It compiles just fine but when I try to call functions in the library after loading it in a script the script says it can't find System.Net.Http.

Both the script and the library are in the same project targeted at .Net 4.5.

The library (in TdApi.fs) does this **open System.Net.Http;** but when the script does this **#load "TdApi.fs"** the error in the interactive window is this **TdApi.fs(6,17): error FS0039: The namespace 'Http' is not defined.**

I'm using VS2012 and am just getting started in F#.

Comment: How are you referencing  the Http library when you are running in the interactive?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting votes to close - I think the OP described the problem as good as he could - this is a common thing that causes confusion to F# newcomers...

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between a compiled library and a script file.

When you compile your `TdApi.fs` file as part of a library project, the dependencies (in your case, the HTTP library) are specified in project properties. The compiler uses the `fsproj` file to find the dependencies (and so everything compiles fine).

When you `#load` your `TdApi.fs` file from a script, it does not know about the project - and so it also does not know about the dependencies. To fix this, you can either use `#r "TdApi.dll"` where `TdApi.dll` is the compiled library, or you can use something like:

```
#r "someplace/System.Net.Http.dll"
#load "TdApi.fs"
```

So, you can use `#r` to explicitly load the HTTP library first and then `TdApi.fs` will see it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas your explanation solved my problem and helped me along my path to learning F#.